# Resize Icon + Text Button in Android

Tags: android, button, image-resizing

I have created a text button with an icon. But my icon is bigger size. How can I create different image size for each resolution?

Note: I am using Android Studio 2.2.3

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.asus.teacher.TeacherActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_eye"
    android:text="Drawable left"
    android:textSize="10dp"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create different image size for each resolution

There is several ways:

1. Use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)
2. There is also third party library which will generate image in different folder like `hdpi , xhdpi , mdpi` etc. you can use [Drawable Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer)
3. There is also online tools for that purpose. Like [This](https://www.img-bak.in/)

For xml: you can set height , width , padding ,margin , gravity etc..

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_eye"
    android:text="Drawable left"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
```

Comment: They are cool but I wonder if  there is any other way to resize an image in the xml file?

Comment: i have edited the answer...if the icon is big you can set a specific size height to the button which wraps the icon...

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your icon using [iconify](http://iconify.online)

You can also use ImageButton and set "adjustViewBound" attribute true in that way you just have to fix the width and height will be adjust according to ratio.